# Apache can't start if PHP error_log is set on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have php installed with apache on a windows server 2012 VM.

```
Apache/2.2.29 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.9
```

In php.ini I have logging enabled and now I want to set a file to log the errors.
Whenever I set

```
error_log = "C:\TEMP"
```

And then try to restart the Apache process can't start and says terminated unexpectedly.
Can you please suggest if I should take care of anything else and how I can track down the issue ?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but did you make sure `C:\TEMP` exists and is not set to read only? Also that the apache service has read / write access to the folder?

Comment: The folder is there and being used for session path and the session files are being generated - In fact when when I set the error_log and try to restart Apache the log file does gets generated - but Apache gets terminated !

Comment: In that case you probebly want to check out the Apache error log. It should be located in a logs directory named apache_error.log or something simular. It should indicate why Apache crashed.

Comment: I checked that and Unfortunately, the Apache error log doesn't provides any information of the crash :S

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to update your question with the last few lines of that log. Even though it might not be interesting, it'll at least exclude it from the list. While you're add it, please also add the last few lines of the Apache access log.

Comment: So did you manage to get apache up and running?

Comment: nope; running without the error logging now.